# Добавить ещё одно значение для записи в cookies

Tags: javascript, cookie

Добрый день.

Есть скрипт, который меняет изображение в верхней части сайта, нужно добавить к нему же, чтобы параллельно устанавливалось изображение в нижней части.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 (function(){ 
 if(getCookie('switcher_bg')){ 
 var bg=getCookie('switcher_bg'); 
 $('#header-content').css({'background-image':'url(http://сайт/img/_'+bg+'full.png)'}); 
 $('#footer-content').css({'background-image':'url(http://сайт/img/'+bg+'min.png)'}); 
 $('#switcher-content a[rel="'+bg+'"]').addClass('active'); 
 };})(); 
 $('#switcher-content a').click(function(){ 
 $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
 $('#header-content').css({ 'background-image':'url(http://сайт/img/_'+this.rel+'full.png)'}); 
 setCookie('switcher_bg',this.rel,365); 
 $('#footer-content').css({ 'background-image':'url(http://сайт/img/'+this.rel+'min.png)'}); 
 setCookie('switcher_bg',this.rel,365); 
 }); 
 </script>
```

Т.е. `#header-content` работает, нужно добавить `#footer-content`.

Запись `cookies` производится этим (находится в отдельном файле):

```
 function setCookie(a,b,c){if(c){var d=new Date();d.setTime(d.getTime()+(c*24*60*60*1000));var e="; expires="+d.toGMTString()}else var e="";document.cookie=a+"="+b+e+"; path=/"}function getCookie(a){var b=a+"=";var d=document.cookie.split(';');for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++){var c=d[i];while(c.charAt(0)==' ')c=c.substring(1,c.length);if(c.indexOf(b)==0)return c.substring(b.length,c.length)}return null}function delCookie(a){setCookie(a,"",-1)}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Help me please!

Comment: а что у вас не получается ? вы просто ничего не понимаете в коде выше и хотите чтобы за вас сделали ?

Comment: Что-то типа того. :) Всё лучше, чем просьбы в соседних постах. Я просто не могу понять, как в cookies подставляются значения из первого скрипта.

Comment: Демонстрация есть тут http://mobi-games.ucoz.ru/

Comment: setCookie('switcher_bg',this.rel,365); ?

Comment: у вас все устанавливается, просто футер под меню заезжает

Comment: Исправил.
Устанавливается, но не записывается в cookies. После обновления страницы ставится значение по умолчанию.
А никто не орёт. Я пишу спокойным тоном. Даже смайлики ставлю. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас footer-content отсутствует на момент выполнения этой функции, сделайте

```
$(function(){
```

вместо

```
(function(){
```

Comment: Так вообще не работает. :(